# Cómo imprimir columnas específicas en una fila determinada de un fichero

Tags: shell, unix, awk, procesamiento-de-texto, cut

Tengo un `fichero.txt` con la siguiente información:

```
1;Pepito;Flores Rubias;3;IT;OCT;PT
2;Juan;Ramirez Rubias;3;IT;LM;PY
3;Joan;Trico Traco;4;IM;ENG;IR
4;Jose;Trigo Limpoio;5;UT;DOM;WE
```

La primera columna es el número de usuario definido por la variable `$numero`.

Necesito poder consultar las tres últimas filas de un usuario, dando el numero de usuario el que ejecuta el programa.

Es decir, necesito el código que busque el número que le das (que corresponde a la primera columna y solo a la primera columna), aisle esa fila, y te muestre las tres últimas columnas de ese usuario. No se si me he explicado.

Lo tengo así, pero claro, no me funciona:

```
cat fichero.txt | (awk -F ";" '{$1}' | grep "$numero") | awk -F ";" '{print $2, $3 ":\n  " $5 "\n 2ª  " $6 "\n 3ª  " $7 "\n" }'
```

Comment: Hola, no es necesario que edites el título de la pregunta con "SOLUCIONADO", simplemente tienes que marcar la respuesta que te ha ayudado al costado izquierdo de la respuesta en donde aparece el check.

Answer (score 6):

Espero haber entendido bien, ten en cuenta que no estoy usando `awk`. Este el archivo de entrada:

```
$ cat fichero.txt
1;Pepito;Flores Rubias;3;IT;OCT;PT
2;Juan;Ramirez Rubias;3;IT;LM;PY
3;Joan;Trico Traco;4;IM;ENG;IR
4;Jose;Trigo Limpoio;5;UT;DOM;WE
```

Ahora algunos ejemplos:

```
$ numero=3
$ cat fichero.txt | grep "^$numero;" | cut -d";" -f5-7
IM;ENG;IR
$ numero=1
$ cat fichero.txt | grep "^$numero;" | cut -d";" -f5-7 
IT;OCT;PT
```

Simplemente estoy buscando el número del usuario definido con `grep` incluyendo el caracter `;`:

```
grep "^$numero;"
```

Con la ayuda de `cut` estoy partiendo la línea usando como delimitador (con la opción `-d`) el caracter `;` y los campos (con la opción `-f`) del 5 al 7:

```
cut -d";" -f5-7
```

Si deseas reemplazar el caracter `;` por, por ejemplo, un espacio vacío, puedes agregar el comando `tr` de esta forma:

```
$ cat fichero.txt | grep "^$numero;" | cut -d";" -f5-7 | tr ";" " "
IT OCT PT
```

O tal vez con un salto de línea:

```
$ cat fichero.txt | grep "^$numero;" | cut -d";" -f5-7 | tr ";" "\n"
IT
OCT
PT
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias, me ha ido perfecto!

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta, así otros igual podrán verlo @DRY !

Comment: Esto es un claro caso de UUOC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat

Answer (score 2):

En `awk` sería simplemente:

```
$ awk -F\; -v numero=1 '$1==numero{print $5,$6,$7}' fichero.txt
```

Con saltos de línea:

```
$ awk -F\; -v user=1 '$1==numero{print $5,$6,$7}' OFS='\n' fichero.txt
IT
OCT
PT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numero=3

grep ^$numero file.txt| awk -F";" '{print $5,$6,$7}'
IM ENG IR
```

Si lo que necesitas es que aparezcan en formato columna:

```
grep ^$numero file.txt| awk -F";" '{print $5,"\n"$6"\n"$7}'
IM 
ENG
IR
```